# Unable to read advertisements via Koala::Facebook API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ads, koala

I have a Rails web app that allows the user to manage Ads from Facebook. This is done through the Koala API as followed:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
result = graph.get_object(ad_group.facebook_adgroup_id, {:fields => "effective_status,configured_status,ad_review_feedback"}, api_version: ENV["ADS_API_VERSION"])
```

This method stopped working, and it is giving me this error:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 278, message: (#278) Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read [HTTP 403]
```

Any advice please ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have access token. You can get it with gem ['fb_graph2'](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph2)

Also you need to create a [facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and get from that your id and secret_key

```
auth = FbGraph2::Auth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"])
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(auth.access_token!)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue unfortunately @Dima I. Belinski